# Comment traduire « jetlag » en français ?

Tags: traduction, demande-de-mot

> *Jetlag* is the feeling of tiredness and confusion that people
>   experience after making a long journey by plane to a place where the
>   time is different from the place they left. [*Source*](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/jet-lag)

*jetlag* is a very common word used in English to described this physiological condition. I was wondering what can be an equivalent in French. As far as I know, there is not a single word for it. The most understandable I've found is *fatigue due au décalage horaire* but it is pretty verbose.

---

*jetlag* est un terme courant en anglais pour définir la fatigue due au décalage horaire. Je me demandais quel pourrait être un équivalent français simple, et moins verbeux que *fatigue due au décalage horaire* (c'est le terme le plus intelligible que j'aie trouvé).

Comment: On parle plutôt des symptômes du décalage horaire (car c'est plus large que la fatigue). L'[avenir de la langue française](http://www.avenir-langue-francaise.fr/articles.php?lng=fr&pg=705&prt=1) parle aussi du « mal ».

Comment: @Laure Effectivement, merci pour ton commentaire. L'expression reste tout de même assez verbeuse, au point que j'entends régulièrement (même en français) l'anglicisme *jetlag*.

Comment: Je suis d’accord que c’est «verbose» +1 cf: En descendant du jumbo jet, le jet-setteur se disait «Mon Dieux, qu'est ce que c'est dur d'être membre du/de la jet-set, j’ai une fatigue due au décalage horaire, pas possible!»

Comment: Ce décalage horaire m'a eu, m'a frappé fort, m'a donné un coup etc.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

L'expression *décalage horaire* est généralement utilisée autour de moi. Le contexte suffit pour comprendre qu'on parle de fatigue et pas de réglages de montres.

Answer (score 6):

On trouve en effet « fatigue due au décalage horaire » dans les dictionnaires anglais-français comme traduction de *jetlag*. Ça exprime bien la notion à un francophone qui rencontrerait ce terme dans un contexte anglais, mais lui fournit bien peu d’outils pour exprimer le concept simplement dans sa langue, ce qui causera naturellement des lourdeurs lorsqu’on voudra intégrer cette notion dans un discours français.

Que faire alors ? Plusieurs avenues sont possibles.

L’emprunt direct en est une, qui semble commune en France (selon un commentaire sous la question) et dans une certaine mesure existante au Québec¹, selon mes propres observations. J’avais évoqué la possibilité que le nom emprunté inspire le verbe

> - jetlaguer

...mais ce serait déjà un fait accompli selon le commentaire de Teleporting Goat ci-dessous.

Par ailleurs, le polymorphe utilisateur aujourd'hui nommé *de la Dauversière* *(et demain qui sait)*, du Québec aussi, dit utiliser les expressions...

> - Être sur le jetlag
> - Être sur le décalage horaire

...construites sur le modèle *« Être sur le lendemain de veille » (avoir la gueule de bois)*, en spécifiant que la tournure pourrait être familière. Ça semble indiquer que l’emprunt peut très bien coexister avec une tentative de francisation de l’expression.

---

Faute d’emprunter, les circonlocutions

> - fatigue due au décalage horaire
> - ne pas être complètement remis du décalage horaire

sont en effet très verbeuses et l’individu moyen n’aime pas utiliser ou devoir entendre à répétition de telles expressions que l’on saisi bientôt immédiatement, mais dont l’énonciation s’étire et s’étire et s’étire, sans apporter quoi que ce soit de neuf à partir du moment où elle est comprise. J’ai observé autour de moi, de la part de voyageurs ou de travailleurs de nuit, ou de moi-même lorsque je voyage, une tendance à y aller de quelque chose qui s’intègre bien au discours, qui n’utilise pas de vocabulaire inhabituel (*souffrir* au Québec est assez rare, par exemple, mais ça peut n’être que local), mais dont la forme est variable, faute d’un terme ou d’une expression déjà bien ancré dans notre langue :

> - J’ai l’horaire (tout) décalé / *[parfois aussi tout simplement, quand le contexte est clair]* Je suis décalé / Je souffre du décalage
> - Je me remets à l’heure d’ici / Je rajuste mon horaire (à l’heure d’ici)
> - Je dois changer le jour pour la nuit
> - *[une version plus populaire du précédent]* J’essaie de revirer le jour pour la nuit → comprendre qu’on tente d’inverser leurs positions respectives

Pour le nom *jetlag* en particulier, lorsque tout le contexte indique que c’est de ce dont on parle, on mentionne tout simplement *décalage*, qui possède bien entendu de nombreuses autres acceptions, mais qui n’interfèrent généralement pas dans une conversation sur le sujet (je sais bien que cette solution ne plaira pas à tout le monde, et qu’un terme plus pointu, plus exact et plus unique serait sans doute nécessaire pour le cas par exemple d’une étude sur le sujet, mais cette méthode a néanmoins fait ses preuves, ne fut-ce que localement).

---

> ¹ L’emprunt direct en général est assez controversé au Québec, et l’on trouvera immanquablement des gens pour s’en insulter haut, fort et durablement. Quoique ça n’empêche guère le phénomène de ressurgir régulièrement, on pourra remarquer que la création d’alternatives françaises à de nouveaux emprunts est une sorte de course contre la montre à laquelle la société québécoise aime prendre part : il s’agit de combattre l’emprunt avant qu’il ne s’établisse trop confortablement. Le succès de ces entreprises est partagé : certains mots ont un grand succès *(courriel)*, d’autres semblent destinés d’emblée à échouer *(égoportrait pour selfie)*.

Comment: "*Est-ce que souffrir de jetlag pourrait devenir Jetlaguer?*" En général en France on dit "être jetlagué" : *Je suis jetlagué de 4h*

Comment: Merci! Je ne connais pas beaucoup la France et mon style de réponse est généralement assez biaisé vers le Québec, ce qui peut poser quelques problèmes lorsque je tente de répondre à des Français qui ne connaissent pas tant le Québec. J'espère toujours que mes réflexions pourront être un tant soit peu utiles, mais c'est parfois difficile à juger. Je chercherai un moyen d'inclure votre information dans ma réponse...

Comment: Pas de soucis ! Ça reste pertinent mais c'est vrai que surtout sur le terrain des anglicismes c'est assez différent entre la France et le Québec.

Comment: Je trouve que pour la plupart des cas, on peut très bien parler du décalage horaire avec un autre verbe. On sait déjà qu'il s'agit de fatigue. Gosh, I have such bad jetlag. Dis donc, le décalage horaire m'a donné ou fait un coup. Il y a beaucoup de tournures comme ça.

Comment: Ainsi que l'a mentionné Mouviciel, on peut parler de décalage horaire, en effet. Je parle de ce que j'entends, pas du possible. Mon cercle est restreint et probablement pas représentatif du Grand Tout, mais il fonctionne et à 6 degrés de séparation, il couvre apparemment l'humanité entière. Je partage ce que j'observe, pas ce que j'estime possible ou ce que je suppose qui se dit hors mon cercle. Toute différence avec l'expérience de qqn d'autre pourra n'être que le fruit de mon incapacité à fréquenter suffisamment de gens.

Comment: Il demeure possible que je n'aie pas prêté suffisamment attention à l'usage de mes proches. Les parties de conversation qui m'intéressent sont peut-être davantage celles où la personne parle de ses efforts ou de son processus en cours pour contrer le décalage que celles où elle décrit son état de façon statique. Je suis peut-être moins capable que d'autres de présenter mon point de vue en montrant bien que je laisse la porte ouverte à des analyses différentes de la situation. Ainsi soit-il!

Comment: C'est intéressant pcq. on s'intéresse à la construction de la phrase. [Larousse](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/anglais-francais/jet-lagged/590111) a justement l'idée de _ne pas être entièrement remis de_ pour _jet lagged_ ; _fatigué par_. A [jetlag](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/anglais-francais/jetlag/590110) comme tel on a _être sous le coup du..._. Perso. je suis familier avec un truc possiblement familier ou un calque ou je ne sais trop, construit sur le modèle d'_être sur le/un lendemain de veille_, donc _être sur_ le décalage horaire ou le _jetlag_. Pas sûr si c'est un/le. Merci.

Answer (score 5):

Je réponds tard, mais bon...

Comme dit précédemment, à côté de *jetlag* et *jetlagué* parmi les jeunes (et les cadres dynamiques qui veulent faire genre ils passent leur temps dans l'avion), on parle tout à fait couramment de *décalage horaire*, et l'on dira "Je souffre encore du décalage horaire", ou "Je ressens le décalage horaire, je me fais mal/je ne me fais pas au décalage horaire, je n'arrive pas à encaisser le décalage, etc.", voire des tournures plus explicites : "je n'arrive pas à me caler à l'horaire d'ici", "je suis resté à l'horaire de là-bas", ou tout simplement "Je suis décalé".

Seulement, je voulais proposer un mot oublié, jamais utilisé dans cette acception (les avions n'existaient pas), mais tout à fait approprié à mon sens : désheurer. "Je suis totalement désheuré", "ce voyage m'a désheuré". Normalement, *désheurer*, c'est retarder quelqu'un dans son emploi du temps réglé heure par heure, ou bousculer ses horaires habituels :

> "Les uns grommel[aient] d'être désheurés et dérangés de leurs habitudes." (Chateaubriand)

De là on est venu à l'appliquer à une idée de perte de la notion de l'heure qu'il est :

> "Les vacances même ne le désheuraient jamais." (Gracq)

Comparez, pour le sens qui nous intéresse :

> "Je l'ai quitté hier matin... Mais non, qu'est-ce que je dis ?... C'est avant-hier... enfin il y a deux jours. On n'imagine pas comme une nuit de voyage vous désheure !" (Daudet) ;

c'est tout à fait ça !

C'est aussi court que *jetlaguer*, cela se conjugue aussi facilement, la formation (donc le sens) est transparente, et c'est bien plus euphonique à mon goût.

Remarque : Enfin dernier sens, une pendule désheurée est une pendule déréglée, qui sonne une heure différente de celle qu'elle affiche ; un train désheuré, un train en retard. Je renvoie au CNRTL pour plus de détails.

Answer (score 3):

Dans un registre familier :

- Je suis [jetlagué](http://dictionnaire.reverso.net/francais-definition/jetlagu%C3%A9,%20%C3%A9e)
- Je suis [décalqué](http://dictionnaire.reverso.net/francais-definition/d%C3%A9calqu%C3%A9) = état de confusion causé par un manque important de sommeil  (expression très probablement d'origine méridionale et qui se répand lentement ailleurs).

Answer (score 2):

[Here’s a pretty cool post](http://citizenlambda.canalblog.com/archives/2011/08/25/21867122.html) (or is it a poem?) on the *Canalblog* of Citizen Lambda that describes well many of the feelings that I experience and associate with jet lag, like being (as the title puts it) “Complètement détraqué” and how, even after going without sleep to try to beat it, one still finds themself wide awake and starving *à trois plombes du mat*, often wondering if it’s already today (or even tomorrow) or if it’s still yesterday.

Granted, the blogger seems to be merely listing some of the symptoms of jetlag and is not suggesting an alternative name for it, but his mention of

> “biorythmes … en recherche de fréquences”

reminded me of how often I’ve described the feeling/fatigue/symptoms of jetlag as “having my internal clock completely out of whack,” which could be described in French as the state of having my

> “biorythmes/rythme circadien/horloge interne complètement (albeit
>   temporarily) détraqué/déréglé(es),

or as it’s called in [paragraph 2 of this University of Geneva 2017 press release](https://www.unige.ch/communication/communiques/2017/cdp200317/),

> “la désynchronisation de nos horloges internes” or “le dérèglement
>   circadien” for short.

Similarly, the French Centre national de la recherche scientifique (CNRS) uses the terms

> «une perturbation des rythmes circadiens» in paragraph 5

and in the singular,

> “une perturbation du rythme circadian” in paragraph 7 of [this 2006
>   press
>   release](http://www2.cnrs.fr/presse/communique/880.htm?&theme=7&debut=32).

Since jetlag is not the only cause of “dérèglement/perturbation [du rythme] circadian,” you would unfortunately still need to add, for the sake of context-neutral clarity, the ever verbose “due au décalage horaire” to it (making it even longer than your “fatigue/symptoms due au … ,”

but where the context is clear, I think the extra words could easily be omitted, for example:

> Ce n’est pas étonnant qu’après 10 heures de vol je souffre pas mal d’un/e dérèglement/perturbation/ [du rythme] circadian//d’une désynchronisation d’horloge interne,

although I seriously doubt that, even in its truncated form, this is the kind of “équivalent français **simple**” that you’re after.

Answer (score 1):

Pour l'instant, il n'y a pas d'équivalent français à *jetlag*.

Soit on utilise un anglicisme, soit un groupe de mots. Personnellement j'utilise *jetlag* régulièrement, tant que je parle avec quelqu'un qui, je pense, comprendra le sens.

Pour moi les anglicismes ne sont pas un problème tant qu'on est compris. Si il y a un mot français tant mieux, sinon tant pis, on ne va pas se priver d'un mot anglais au profit d'une expression plus lourde.

Comment: @Mistalis On a parfois des question du type "quel est le mot français pour ça ?", où clairement il n'y a pas de mot, mais la réponse " il n'y a pas de mot" n'est pas satisfaisante pour l'OP est n'est jamais acceptée.

Comment: Mais tout le monde dit le décalage horaire. Pensez à comment on parle en réalité: Last week, I had terrible jetlag. On va dire là en français quelque chose comme: Le semaine dernière, quel coup [de barre] à cause du décalage horaire. A-t-on besoin vraiment d'un seul mot? La plupart du temps on dit des choses qui ressemblent à ce genre de phrase.

Comment: @Lambie Je n'ai pas la prétention de parler au nom de tout le monde, mais quand je dis "*Personnellement j'utilise* jetlag" c'est que personnellement j'utilise *jetlag*, dans la réalité. Et les gens avec qui je parle aussi. Et le décalage horaire c'est la cause du jetlag,  pas le jetlag lui-même, je comprends pas trop ta remarque. On a peut-être être pas le même vocabulaire, mais je t'invite à écrire une réponse avec le tien plutôt.

Comment: Je n'ai absolumment rien  contre jetlag. Mon objection se centre sur l'idée qu'on doit traduire le mot en lui-même quand le contexte permet d'exprimer l'idée en français autrement. C'est tout. On a tendance à s'accrocher au mot et souvent d'oublier le contexte et faire du mot à mot.

Answer (score 1):

Formally called 'le décalage horaire'.  Mais moi je ne connais personne qui dise 'jetlaggué', tous les gens que je connais disent 'décalé', comme dans 'je suis rentré la semaine derniere et je suis encore un peu décalé'.